# How do I locally simulate accessing a Dynamics CRM database for use with SOAP?

Tags: php, database, soap, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am currently starting on a project for school where we are to make a prototype for an application that uses PHP and SOAP to access a Dynamics CRM server.

So far I've gotten my apache server up and running and a project set up in Netbeans, simple .php files work just fine...

Now I'd need a similar database as is used in a MS Dynamics CRM system that I can run locally (so no network connection or configuration is required). Connection to the actual database (of the company we make the prototype for) is impossible.

An SQL server would be the easiest option I know of (according to a post here MySQL is incompatible with the dynamics database so that's not an option) since we have used this in class already, but is this a comparable database to the one used in Dynamics CRM?

This assignment is slightly out of my league since I have had no experience with PHP or SOAP coding, but then again we only need to simulate a couple of simple insert/update/delete/... statements - only problem being I have no idea how I should simulate their database.

Thanks in advance for you help, feel free to ask any extra questions if you need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having a database isn't going to be enough here. Dynamics CRM is the application which has the SOAP web service endpoint and then performs any actions on the database.

You cannot just run SOAP calls directly against the database and you should not be directly editing the CRM database - its not supported by Microsoft.

What you really need is a full development environment - CRM, SQL, AD the whole setup.

So traditionally you might go for a local server with CRM On-Premise, SQL and all their prerequisites installed, not a cheap option and it sounds like it might be beyond your current resources.

So my suggestion would be to go for CRM Online - basically Microsoft host everything and you access CRM via the web. CRM Online is basically the same as CRM On-Premise, there are some key differences but you will be able to perform all your SOAP calls against a real working CRM.

Even better CRM Online has a 30-Day free trial, after that its a $44 a month per user, but as I understand you can just keep creating more free trials.

Also you then need to get your clients customisations installed on the environment. You can export those from CRM and import them into your development environment. You can do this without taking an live data - which is probably why the client doesn't want to give you their database. The reason this is important is so you have the correct data model which is very important for the SOAP web service calls.

In regards to the PHP SOAP bits you might want to have a look at: [PHP MSCRM](http://phpmscrm.codeplex.com/), I haven't used it myself but it looks useful.

As a side, you may want to look at the OData endpoint of MSCRM you may find it more straightforward to use from PHP.

Comment: This is what I was fearing for. This prototype isn't meant to be implemented anywhere soon (it's a pretty big company, nothing a 2-person team of students can handle in totality) but it's a big part of our class this semester so they expect us to have a realistic environment built up.

The on-premise is definitely out of reach, but the 30-day trial seems like it should work. We can show that we know how to interact with a real CRM system (even though it has very few customisations). In theory it is just more work to do the same thing with a complex, working, system.

Comment: Well I would definitely have a look at CRM Online, you can have a full environment setup very rapidly. It's an enterprise environment so its about as realistic as it gets.

Comment: Thank you very much then. We'll take a look at it and see where we get! If you have any other tips, I'll gladly accept. :)
(At this moment i'm not rating my future grades very high, but no pain, no gain!)

Comment: I'm not getting past making a new soapclient. What parameters am I supposed to give with the new soapClient() function? there are examples enough but nowhere it's really explained what is being referenced (i.e. new nusoap_client("http://6.jvatv.ru/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx", 'wsdl');)

Then there's also the question of authentication - I simply have no idea how to get started on these things.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://company_name.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc' : failed to load external entity 

As example

Comment: after putting the file locally on my C: drive, I'm getting this error
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't bind to service in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPAdminMngr\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPAdminMngr\index.php(15): SoapClient->SoapClient('C:\Users\...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPAdminMngr\index.php on line 15

Comment: I don't have any more tips on general on this point. If you went with my CRM online suggestion i would suggest marking this as answered. If you have moved on and got stuck on something else make a new question with your code, it will get a better response.